# Difference between eventListener and event.target on this question

Tags: javascript, html, events, event-handling, event-listener

Im trying to solve a simple problem in Js, where i need to rotate a string in js(only) on my html, but im facing problems with this two event handlers(im calling eventListener and event.target of event handlers because im not sure if they do the same thing or similar...).

Here is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="Training">
        <meta name="author" content="Vitor Mota">
        <title>Training</title><!--Practice-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">                      
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssFile.css">
        <script src="JsExc.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body >

       
       <div class="Test_space" id="target">
        <button id="btnStart">Start</button>
          <div id="tt">w3resource</div> 
        <button id="btnStop">Stop</button>    
       </div>

        
       
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my code in JS (whose not working when im using  `if(event.target == btnStop){   }` and  `let btnStop= document.getElementById("btnStop");`):

```
window.onclick = function(event){
    


    let Startbtn = document.getElementById("btnStart");
    let btnStop= document.getElementById("btnStop");

    let getId= document.getElementById("tt"); //Any id name
    let getSstringToReplace = getId.childNodes[0].data;


    let myInterval 
    

    if(event.target == btnStart){   
        myInterval = setInterval(start, 100);
    }

    if(event.target == btnStop){   
          clearInterval(myInterval);
    }

    function start(){   
        getSstringToReplace= getSstringToReplace[getSstringToReplace.length-1] + getSstringToReplace.substring(0, getSstringToReplace.length - 1);  
        
        getId.childNodes[0].data = getSstringToReplace;
    }
    
}
```

but when i change that part of the code `if(event.target == btnStop){   }` and   `let btnStop= document.getElementById("btnStop");`
, and add a new function stop() and change my getelementbyid to addEventListener, like here:

```
window.onclick = function(event){
    


    let Startbtn = document.getElementById("btnStart");
    document.getElementById("btnStop").addEventListener("click", stop);

    let getId= document.getElementById("tt");
    let getSstringToReplace = getId.childNodes[0].data;


    let myInterval 
    

    if(event.target == Startbtn){   
        myInterval = setInterval(run, 100);
    }
    function stop(){
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
    function run(){   
        getSstringToReplace= getSstringToReplace[getSstringToReplace.length-1] + getSstringToReplace.substring(0, getSstringToReplace.length - 1);  
        
        getId.childNodes[0].data = getSstringToReplace;
    }
    
}
```

this one work, someone can explain why?

Comment: You have `let myInterval` scoped to the click handler, meaning every time you click you get a new instance of myInterval, the second one works only because you creating a brand new event handlers for the currently scoped myInterval.   So basically every time you click your creating another Event handlers, basically causing a memory leak.

Comment: but if i put MyInterval scoped to btn start, stop it wont work on the second function (event.target == btnStop), right ? it is away from that scop.

Comment: Your scope needs lifting, IOW: it needs moving before `window.onclick`,  this means when you click again it will see the same myInterval and not create another one.

Comment: catch it. Prevent from leaking. Amazing bro, work perfectly fine, thanks a lot. I was searching for a difference between eventlistenet and event target, can you short answer to me ? or are  they absolutely differente from each other? i alredy found that event target relate to the object element itself, and eventlistener catch the action, kind of.

Comment: Not sure what your asking there, but MDN have a really good write up on Events, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events  There is even a section on event delegation, that is kind of where target is useful.